# Formatting issue with moment.js - date does not get formatted

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I have dates coming in in this format 31-AUG-2019 and I need to do some date comparisons in .js code so I am using moment.js like this

```
var duedate = "31-AUG-2019";
var rowDueDate = moment(duedate).format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
```

The issue is that I am getting Invalid Date. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `moment(duedate)` doesn't understand the input format

Comment: Obviously! I understand that. My question is how do I fix it. I followed their documentation and got nowhere.

Comment: tell moment the date format your string is in ... `moment('31-AUG-2000', 'DD-MMM-YYYY')`

Comment: Thanks! I thought that's what I was doing! can you please add this as answer? thanks!

Comment: no, you were specifying the **output** format

Comment: What Jaromanda suggested is clearly documented at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/ . As mentioned, this is a problem with the **input** (i.e. parsing). What you were doing with .format() (documented separately at https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) was **output**.

Answer (score 0):

moment('31-AUG-2000', 'DD-MMM-YYYY')